# Highslide: is it possible to send a background request to a php script when opening a photo?

Tags: highslide

I use What is Highslide JS to show photos on my website. I like it very much but the problem is that users want to know some statistics - nicknames of people who have viewed their photos, number of hits for each photo, etc.

Is there any way how to add additional details (like id="25-478" in my example)  to a link and send them to a php script when user opens a photo with Highslide JS?

```
<a href="/x.jpg" class="highslide" id="25-478" onclick="return hs.expand(this,{slideshowGroup: 'grp1'})"><img src="/x.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Highslide itself has no solution for using php script. But maybe you can use [captionID](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.captionId) or [hs.custom](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.custom)